# ASP.Net MVC3 FormsAuthentication overall logged-in event

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, events, formsauthentication, httpapplication

I have an ASP.Net MVC3 app. When the LogIn action is called, I use the MembershipProvider to validate the user and FormsAuthentication to set the cookie.

Additionally, I get some info about the user from a database and store it in Session.

When the user subsequently visits the site, they're already authenticated via the cookie, and I'm looking for somewhere to hook into so I can fetch the info about the user from the database again.

Is HttpApplication.AuthorizeRequest() the best place to do this? Obviously this is called for every request so I was hoping there was something I could use that just indicated the user had been authenticated - either explicitly after logging in or when they're authenticated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several events that get triggered on every request, `HttpApplication.AuthorizeRequest()` should work.

In order to only fetch from the database for logged in users, you can check the `Name` property of `User.Identity` which only gets set once the user authenticates:

```
if(!string.IsEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
{
 //make call to database
}
```